# Функции в javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript, синтаксис

Есть код для 3х слайдеров. Как правильно свести до одной функции?
Ответ лучше без кода -- учу JS.

```
$(function () {
//Slider for module

      if(jQuery("#items-recent-products").length){
          var totalItemsMain1 = jQuery("#items-recent-products > div").length,
          itemWidthMain1 = jQuery(".td").outerWidth(true),
          totalWidthMain1 = itemWidthMain1 * totalItemsMain1,
          visibleItemsMain1 = Math.round(jQuery("#scrollable-recent-products").width() / itemWidthMain1),
          visibleWidthMain1 = visibleItemsMain1 * itemWidthMain1,
          stopPositionMain1 = (visibleWidthMain1 - totalWidthMain1);
      }

      jQuery("#items-recent-products").width(totalWidthMain1);

      jQuery("#prev-recent-products").click(function(){
        if(jQuery("#items-recent-products").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#items-recent-products").is(":animated")){
        jQuery("#items-recent-products").animate({left : "+=" + itemWidthMain1 + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#next-recent-products").click(function(){
        if(jQuery("#items-recent-products").position().left > stopPositionMain1 && !jQuery("#items-recent-products").is(":animated")){
        jQuery("#items-recent-products").animate({left : "-=" + itemWidthMain1 + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });

//First slider for mainpage

      if(jQuery("#items-main-1").length){
          var totalItemsMain1 = jQuery("#items-main-1 > div").length,
          itemWidthMain1 = jQuery(".item-1").outerWidth(true),
          totalWidthMain1 = itemWidthMain1 * totalItemsMain1,
          visibleItemsMain1 = Math.round(jQuery("#scrollable-main-1").width() / itemWidthMain1),
          visibleWidthMain1 = visibleItemsMain1 * itemWidthMain1,
          stopPositionMain1 = (visibleWidthMain1 - totalWidthMain1);
      }
      if(totalItemsMain1>4){
          jQuery("#items-main-1").width(totalWidthMain1);
      }

      jQuery("#prev-main-1").click(function(){
        if(jQuery("#items-main-1").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#items-main-1").is(":animated")){
        jQuery("#items-main-1").animate({left : "+=" + itemWidthMain1 + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#next-main-1").click(function(){
        if(jQuery("#items-main-1").position().left > stopPositionMain1 && !jQuery("#items-main-1").is(":animated")){
        jQuery("#items-main-1").animate({left : "-=" + itemWidthMain1 + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });

//Second slider for mainpage

      if(jQuery("#items-main-2").length){
          var totalItemsMain2 = jQuery("#items-main-2 > div").length,
          itemWidthMain2 = jQuery(".item-2").outerWidth(true),
          totalWidthMain2 = itemWidthMain2 * totalItemsMain2,
          visibleItemsMain2 = Math.round(jQuery("#scrollable-main-2").width() / itemWidthMain2),
          visibleWidthMain2 = visibleItemsMain2 * itemWidthMain2,
          stopPositionMain2 = (visibleWidthMain2 - totalWidthMain2);
      }

      if(totalItemsMain2>4){
          jQuery("#items-main-2").width(totalWidthMain2);
      }

      jQuery("#prev-main-2").click(function(){
        if(jQuery("#items-main-2").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#items-main-2").is(":animated")){
        jQuery("#items-main-2").animate({left : "+=" + itemWidthMain2 + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#next-main-2").click(function(){
        if(jQuery("#items-main-2").position().left > stopPositionMain2 && !jQuery("#items-main-2").is(":animated")){
        jQuery("#items-main-2").animate({left : "-=" + itemWidthMain2 + "px"});
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделить аналогичные куски, параметризировать (например itemId, scrollableId), оформить в виде функции, вызвать функцию три раза с параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего оформить в виде плагина jQuery

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.slider = function(options){
 var options = $.extend({
  animationSpeed: 'tr-even'
 },options);
 return this.each(function() {
        var totalItemsMain1 = $(this).find('div').length,
      itemWidthMain1 = $(this).find(".item-1").outerWidth(true);    
 });
};
})(jQuery)
```

Вы передаете в плагин контейнер для слайдера, а плагин сам ишет нужные элементы, вешает им события, делает нужные вычисления. В плагине можно сделать удобные настройки, как для примера: скорость анимации.